# How to delete route stack from 1 - length in react native Navigator?

Tags: react-native, navigator

Is there a way to delete some route from my route stack using React-Native Navigator?
I want to achieve this:

```
My Route = [A,B,C,D,E]
-- > I want to push from 'E' to 'F',
-- > I want to delete the route stack into = [A,F]
```

but using popToPop then push to 'A' will change the screen focus, and I want to achieve this in the background process, maybe when componentDidMount in 'F', is there a way to achieve this? I've read the route stack and I think I cannot easily delete the stack, but i cannot find a function to do this, i use react-native 0.39.2 and to update the version would kill me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling a reset action
navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack(['A']) after pushing F ? which will make your stack to be [A,F]

Comment: immediatelyResetRouteStack would call componentWillMount & componentDidMount from 'A', I think it is not clean enough to my goal but I think it works